# How to undo lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

I lost my Phone. I remotely blocked the screen via my Google account. I found my phone back. Now I have to use the password every time I want to use my phone.    How can I undo the remotely installed block?

Answer (score 0):

you can change or remove PIN lock from **Settings > Screen lock**, then you must enter your PIN code (set from remotely lock) and press **Next**, in **choose screen lock** page you can select **No lock screen** from list or select another lock method and change your PIN code, Goodluck ... ;)